# NFC NDEF MIME TYPE text/html

Tags: android, nfc, ndef

I am trying to store a very small (1K) html file on a NFC tag.
When read by a phone, it should trigger the Browser to open it.

Sadly I have those constrains :

- **HTML file (1kb) Stored on the tag. Not just a url.** (The user don't have internet)
- Not text/plain, it should be text/html.
- It should be opened by the default browser, not a custom tailored app.

I created the tag this way :

> ```
>       Tag detectedTag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
>       NdefRecord record = NdefRecord.createMime( "text/html", "Hello world in <b>HTML</b> !");
>       NdefMessage message = new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord[] { record });
>       if (writeTag(message, detectedTag)) {
>           Toast.makeText(this, "Success: Wrote placeid to nfc tag", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
>               .show();
>       }
> ```

But for some reason, when the tag is read, the default browser is not opened. Even though the browser do have the right intent filter:

> ```
>         <!-- For these schemes where any of these particular MIME types have been supplied, we are a good candidate. -->
>         <intent-filter>
>             <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
>             <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
>             <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
>             <data android:scheme="http" />
>             <data android:scheme="https" />
>             <data android:mimeType="text/html"/>
>             <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
>             <data android:mimeType="application/xhtml+xml"/>
>             <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml"/>
>         </intent-filter>
> ```

Did I do something wrong ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm..

Apparently it is not possible, the manifest specifies this :

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Browser/+/ics-mr0/AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <!-- Accept inbound NFC URLs at a low priority -->
    <intent-filter android:priority="-101">
        <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:scheme="http" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
    </intent-filter>
```

That's so restrictive. No wonder why QR codes win over NFC.

Please, vote for my feature request if you think so too !

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=68668

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the record as a URI. Such as:

`NdefRecord rtdUriRecord1 = NdefRecord.createUri("http://example.com");`

Comment: I need to store the HTML page on the tag itself, in my user case, I can assume that the user doesn't have internet.